# Searching for a substring with leading and trailing spaces in a database using Vyas Kondreddi's stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am searching for a string called 'Ong' in my database, using this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC SearchAllTables
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

    -- Copyright © 2002 Narayana Vyas Kondreddi. All rights reserved.
    -- Purpose: To search all columns of all tables for a given search string
    -- Written by: Narayana Vyas Kondreddi
    -- Site: http://vyaskn.tripod.com
    -- Tested on: SQL Server 7.0 and SQL Server 2000
    -- Date modified: 28th July 2002 22:50 GMT


    CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
    SET  @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                        OBJECT_ID(
                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                             ), 'IsMSShipped'
                               ) = 0
        )

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName =
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                    AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                    AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                    AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
            )

            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                )
            END
        END 
    END

    SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
END
```

I also have a table containing records such as these: (generated from Kondreddi's stored procedure:)

```
1 -- Felicidad T.E. Sagalongos
2 -- Bob Ong
3 -- Bob Ong
4 -- Bob Ong
5 -- Bob Ong
6 -- Bob Ong
7 -- Komunikasyon sa Akademikong Filipino
8 -- Book Of Tongue Twisters For English & Students
9 -- Diksiyunaryong Ingles-Pilipino Pilipino-Ingles
10 -- Hong Kong Apothecary: A Visual History of Chinese Medicine Packaging
11 -- A Song of Ice and Fire
12 -- Ang Paboritong Libro ni Hudas
```

The thing is, I want to search for a particular string, "Ong", and the only results I want to show are those written "Bob Ong" or "Shirley Ong". I don't want words like "Song" and "Hong Kong" to appear. I tried using spaces. It gives me blank results. Is there another way?

Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

from this part of your query please remove (%) character:

```
QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr,'''')
```

Comment: It kinda works. Only that there's a catch: For example, I search for 'Bob' in 'Bob Ong', it returns nothing, when I wish it would return Bob Ong as well.